# How to locate the intra dct Coefficient in blocks of mpeg-4 visual stream?

Tags: mpeg-4

is there any 'easy' way to locate the specific syntax unit(like an intra dct coefficient in 8x8 blocks) in a mpeg4 visual stream?

or just say , the only way to do it is analysing the stream with all the detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No easy way at all. You have to decode the stream to get those.
EDIT
Use ffmpeg to get those. A single fprintf in the right place should give it to you.

Comment: Welcome. Accepting the answer would be a nice thank you :).  Use ffmpeg to get it. A few fwrites in the right place will give you all syntactic elements. To cross verify you can use elecard analyzer. Its a windows tool but it is very good. The demo version allows you to go upto 200 frames. There is also something called codecvisa for linux but only 2 frames for demo mode.